# Cancel perform selector method in recursion

Tags: ios, repeat, performselector

I am repeating a function again and again using this code

```
- (void)refresh {
[self performSelector:@selector(refresh) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
}
```

On `viewWillDisappear` I wrote the code to cancel this but still the function called. How can we cancel this perform selector repeating itself ?

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];    
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(refresh) object:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

please First of all , check this you might be running on different run loops in creation and cancellation.I faced this problem in past.

or

I think no need to write selector again. Just right this and try.

With this

```
// cancel the above call (and any others on self)
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```

Refer apples document.

[NSObject_Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html)

> Discussion All perform requests are canceled that have the same target
>   as aTarget, argument as anArgument, and selector as aSelector. This
>   method removes perform requests only in the current run loop, not all
>   run loops.